# how to catch an exception and does not stop the code from executing

Tags: java

i want to catch an InputMissmatchException but not stopping the code from re-executing(i want the while loop to re-run again until an appropriate input is given)

int choice = 0;
        boolean loop = true;

```
    while(loop){
        printInstruction();
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        //catch InputMissmatchException

        switch(choice){
            case 0:
                loop = false;
                break;

            case 1:
                addCustomer(mohamad,sgbl);
                break;

            case 2:
                deleteCustomer(sgbl);
                break;

            case 3:
                seeInfo(sgbl);
                break;

            case 4:
                makeTransaction(mohamad);
                break;

            case 5:
                seeTransactionLog(mohamad);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("try again");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Put the try around all scanner usage and catch within the loop. It won't stop.

Comment: Basically you want to swallow the exception so wrap your statements in try and catch and do nothing in the catch block just add some logs. If you catch Exception all type of exceptions would be swallowed including unchecked exception or you can be more specific to your exception.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
int a = -1;
while(true)
{
  try
  {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      a = in.nextInt();
  }
  catch(InputMismatchException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();   
  }

  //Your switch statement 
 }
```

In the way default value for a is set to -1. If exception occurs then value when entering switch case will be -1.

```
int a = -1;
while(true)
{
  try
  {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      a = in.nextInt();
  }
  catch(InputMismatchException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();   
      continue;
  }

  //Your switch statement 
 }
```

If you use continue then current iteration of loop is stopped and runs next iteration